# What did Fairy 2 do there?

Tags: maleficent, maleficent-mistress-of-evil

At the beginning of the *Maleficent: Mistress of Evil* (2019), fairies talk to each other:

> Fairy 1: Do you think Queen Aurora's awake yet?
>
> Fairy 2: Well, she's not "Sleeping Beauty" anymore.
>
> Fairy 3: I see **what you did there**.

What did Fairy 2 do there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

“I see what you did there” in this context means “I got the pun or joke you just made”. The previous line is a pun, I assume, as it’s referring to the title of the source story which is kind of breaking the fourth wall.

Comment: It's a pun, indeed. Fairy 1 is asking if Aurora is awake, and Fairy 2 is joking with the fact that she's not cursed anymore (thus, not longer the Sleeping Beauty)